# Emacs process list seems not to work

Tags: emacs, process

I am experimenting processes in emacs/ielm for a sort of parallel computing, i.e. to start many processes for different computations and then to wait for all the processes have  terminated to compose the result. In order to do this I set up the following simple function:

```
(defun testp ()
  (while (> (length (process-list)) 1)))
```

I call testp after all the child-processes have been started and, when I get again the control, I compose the result:

1. If there are no child-processes testp exits immediately: ok;
2. If there is at least one child-process testp loops: ok;
3. When all child-processes have finished testp continues looping, and this is
   not good.

May I ask you to help me understand where I am wrong.

Comment: What does `(process-list)` evaluate to when you interrupt `(testp)` with `C-g` in case #3?

Answer (score 2):

After a process finishes, it is not necessarily deleted immediately. So `(process-list)` may still list it. The user variable `delete-exited-processes` controls this, so check that you have set it to `t`. The function `list-processes` will also explicitly delete finished processes, so that may be helpful.

Check out the chapter on [processes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Processes.html) in the manual for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs is single-threaded and doesn't handle external input (e.g. about the change in a process's status) until it reaches a "safe point".  So the above loop (as @juanleon suggests) is "too tight".  You want to add a `sleep` into it.

But better is to use `set-process-sentinel` so that Emacs gets told when the processes end rather than having to busy-wait for it.
E.g.:

```
  ...start a new process stored in proc...
  (push proc my-list-of-running-processes)
  (set-process-sentinel proc #'my-run-when-its-over)
  ...

(defun my-run-when-its-over (proc msg)
  (setq my-list-of-running-processes (delq proc my-list-of-running-processes))
  (unless my-list-of-running-processes
    (message "Haha!  all my processes are done!")))
```

Note also that you probably don't want to use `process-list` since that can contain unrelated processes (e.g. if you use `M-x shell` or various other things), which is why I used `my-list-of-running-processes` above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the tight loop is not letting emacs do a proper process cleanup.  My recommendation would be to apply a filter to the result of `(process-list)` (since if you have a runnning compilations, server, shell, etc. the process list won't be empty), to filter out processes different of those you are interested in, and also to add a small delay to the `while` (`(sleep 0 500)`, for instance).